# Stop Loss and Exit Condition

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading

I'm working on a Tradingview Pinescript strategy. I initiate a short position when the RSI falls below 60. I'd like to incorporate a 50-point stop loss into this strategy. The exit condition is when the RSI drops below 40 and then crosses above 50, at which point my open position should be closed instantly.

Code:

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="RSI", process_orders_on_close=true, use_bar_magnifier=true, overlay=true)

// RSI
rsi = ta.rsi(close, input.int(14, title="RSI Period"))

// Entry
if ta.crossunder(rsi, 60)
    strategy.entry("Enter Short", strategy.short)

// Exit
if ta.crossover(rsi, 50)
    strategy.close("Enter Short", comment="Exit Short")
```

I attempted to implement a stop with "stop=50" and "loss=50," but it didn't function correctly.

My current exit strategy seems flawed since it closes the position even if the RSI drops to 49 and then crosses above 50. I require it to stay below 40 at a minimum before closing above 50 for the position to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strategy.close()` is used for conditional closes. So, if you want to close your position based on an RSI value, use that.

`strategy.exit()` is used for exits based on some price. If you want to have SL and TP, use this. You can use the `profit` and `loss` arguments. They expect the target to be specified in **ticks**. So, you might need to convert points to ticks.

Comment: Thanks! Using strategy.exit() did the trick. Can you help me figure out how to setup the RSI condition for exits? As you can see in my code I'm entering the trade when rsi crosses below 60. I want to stay in the trade until RSI touches 40 once and then bounces back to 50. I will need to track the event where RSI touched 40 after my entry and close the position when it hits 50.

Comment: You need to use a `var` variable to see if the RSI touched 40. And then check that variable when the RSI goes above 50. Give it a try and ask a new question if it is not clear.

Comment: I have accepted your answer with the correct one and have opened new questions for my other queries. Please check if you can. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77265770/trail-stop-loss-to-cost

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77266458/exit-position-based-on-rsi-movement